# Not enough funds for a transaction example in testrpc

Tags: solidity, transactions, truffle, testrpc

I try to test one of my first Smart Contract in Solidity, a simple sub currency example, as you can see below :

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.0;

contract Coin {

  address public owner;
  mapping (address => uint) balances;



  function Coin() {
    owner = msg.sender;
    balances[tx.origin] = 1000;
  }


  function send(address receiver, uint amount) returns (bool success) {
    if (balances[msg.sender] < amount) {
      return  false;
    }
    balances[msg.sender] -= amount;
    balances[receiver] += amount;
    return true;

  }


  function getBalance (address user) constant returns (uint balance) {
    return balances[user];
  }
}
```

After migration and compile, please look my truffle command in the console

```
> var a = web3.eth.accounts[0]
> var b = web3.eth.accounts[1]
> var coin = Coin.deployed()
> coin.then(function(instance) {return instance.getBalance.call(a);})
{ [String: '1000'] s: 1, e: 3, c: [ 1000 ] }
> coin.then(function(instance) {return instance.getBalance.call(b);})
> { [String: '0'] s: 1, e: 0, c: [ 0 ] }
```

At this point I'm agree with these output, but when I want to make the transaction, they said I don't have enough funds ...:

```
> coin.then(function(instance) {return instance.send(b,500);})
Error: Error: sender doesn't have enough funds to send tx. The upfront cost is: 724579920256558730963659928732440307373701337785 and the senders account only has: 99835768400000000000
    at runCall (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ethereumjs-testrpc/node_modules/ethereumjs-vm/lib/runTx.js:97:10)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/ethereumjs-testrpc/node_modules/ethereumjs-vm/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:3686:9
    at replenish (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ethereumjs-testrpc/node_modules/ethereumjs-vm/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:882:17)
    at iterateeCallback (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ethereumjs-testrpc/node_modules/ethereumjs-vm/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:867:17)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/ethereumjs-testrpc/node_modules/ethereumjs-vm/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:840:16
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/ethereumjs-testrpc/node_modules/ethereumjs-vm/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:3691:13
    at apply (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ethereumjs-testrpc/node_modules/ethereumjs-vm/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:21:25)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/ethereumjs-testrpc/node_modules/ethereumjs-vm/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:56:12
    at Object.async.eachSeries (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ethereumjs-testrpc/node_modules/async-eventemitter/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:130:20)
    at VM.AsyncEventEmitter.emit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ethereumjs-testrpc/node_modules/async-eventemitter/lib/AsyncEventEmitter.js:42:9)
    at Object.InvalidResponse (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/node_modules/truffle-contract/node_modules/web3/lib/web3/errors.js:35:16)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/node_modules/truffle-contract/node_modules/web3/lib/web3/requestmanager.js:86:36
    at XMLHttpRequest.request.onreadystatechange (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/node_modules/web3/lib/web3/httpprovider.js:119:13)
    at XMLHttpRequestEventTarget.dispatchEvent (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/node_modules/xhr2/lib/xhr2.js:64:18)
    at XMLHttpRequest._setReadyState (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/node_modules/xhr2/lib/xhr2.js:354:12)
    at XMLHttpRequest._onHttpResponseEnd (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/node_modules/xhr2/lib/xhr2.js:509:12)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/node_modules/xhr2/lib/xhr2.js:469:24)
    at emitNone (events.js:91:20)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:185:7)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:974:12)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:74:11)
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:122:9)
```

I tried with other accounts available in Testrpc, I've same results ... May be I missed something in my command or set up I Don't know. But this cost seems to important, no ?

Thanks for your help !

Comment: In your contract code, seems, getBalance should return the same value `balances[owner]` everytime for any address.  Is this the same contract you used in your truffle tests?

Comment: Thanks for this good remark ! wrong copy/paste of the version of my code... it's `balances[user]` and not `balances[owner]` !

Answer (score 3):

In your project folder, you should have a genesis.json file (in one of the directories).

According to [that page](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Ethereum-Chain-Spec-Format) it seems you can define balances amount for the accounts:

```
 "accounts": {
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000001": { "balance": "1", "nonce": "1048576", "builtin": { "name": "ecrecover", "pricing": { "linear": { "base": 3000, "word": 0 } } } },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000002": { "balance": "1", "nonce": "1048576", "builtin": { "name": "sha256", "pricing": { "linear": { "base": 60, "word": 12 } } } },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000003": { "balance": "1", "nonce": "1048576", "builtin": { "name": "ripemd160", "pricing": { "linear": { "base": 600, "word": 120 } } } },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000004": { "balance": "1", "nonce": "1048576", "builtin": { "name": "identity", "pricing": { "linear": { "base": 15, "word": 3 } } } },
    "102e61f5d8f9bc71d0ad4a084df4e65e05ce0e1c": { "balance": "1606938044258990275541962092341162602522202993782792835301376", "nonce": "1048576" }
```

Answer (score 1):

This simple test works for your contract, if you'll run it with `truffle test`:

```
contract('Coin', function(accounts) {
  it("works", function() {
    var coin = Coin.deployed();

    var a = accounts[0];
    var b = accounts[1];

    getBalances(coin, a, b, function() {
       coin.send(b,500).then(function() {
        getBalances(coin, a, b);
       });
    })
  });
});

function getBalances(coin, a, b, cb) {
  coin.getBalance.call(a).then(function(balanceA) {
    console.log("balanceA: " + balanceA);

    coin.getBalance.call(b).then(function(balanceB) {
      console.log("balanceB: " + balanceB);
      if (cb)
        cb();
    });
  });
}
```

The output:

```
balanceA: 1000
balanceB: 0
balanceA: 500
balanceB: 500
```

Comment: This shouldn't be marked as correct answer, as it doesn't answer the question at all ..

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue and I think 'send' is already used as a function name / keyword and can't be used as a function name in the contract (at-least if we wish to interact with it through the truffle console). When I change the name of the send function to 'sendCoin' or something that isn't 'send' and redeploy then the above error goes away.

If you do: `Coin.deployed().then(function(contractDesc) {console.log(contractDesc)})` the functions available from that contract are listed and at the bottom there is already a send function defined `send: [Function],`. I'm not sure how to interpret this definition properly but I guess we can't have two of the same.

Answer (score 1):

Restart `testrpc` and the problem will be solved.

Answer (score 0):

`send` method is a reserved method for each contract, just simply change the `send` method in `Coin` contract to `sendAmount` or other name, it will work.

Refer: https://github.com/sgyyz/solidity-learning/issues/1